# Is there an API that allows ordering event in clustered application?

Tags: java, events

Given the following facts, is there a existing open-source Java API (possibly as part of some greater product) that implements an algorithm enabling the reproducible ordering of events in a cluster environment:

```
1) There are N sources of events, each with a unique ID.
2) Each event produced has an ID/timestamp, which, together with
   its source ID, makes it uniquely identifiable.
3) The ids can be used to sort the events.
4) There are M application servers receiving those events.
   M is normally 3.
5) The events can arrive at any one or more of the application
   servers, in no specific order.
6) The events are processed in batches.
7) The servers have to agree for each batch on the list of events
   to process.
8) The event each have earliest and latest batch ID in which they
   must be processed.
9) They must not be processed earlier, and are "failed" if they
   cannot be processed before the deadline.
10) The batches are based on the real clock time. For example,
    one batch per second.
11) The events of a batch are processed when 2 of the 3 servers
    agree on the list of events to process for that batch (quorum).
12) The "third" server then has to wait until it possesses all the
    required events before it can process that batch too.
13) Once an event was processed or failed, the source has to be
    informed.
14) [EDIT] Events from one source must be processed (or failed) in
    the order of their ID/timestamp, but there is no causality
    between different sources.
```

Less formally, I have those servers that receive events. They start with the same initial state, and should keep in sync by agreeing on which event to process in which order. Luckily for me, the events are not to be processed ASAP, but "in a bit", so that I have some time to get the servers to agree before the deadline. But I'm not sure if that actually make any real difference to the algorithms. And if all servers agree on all batches, then they will always be in sync, therefore presenting a consistent view when queried.

While I would be most happy with a Java API, I would accept something else if I can call it from Java. And if there is no open-source API, but a clear algorithm, I would also take that as an answer and try to implement it myself.

Comment: Are you at all familiar with distributed algorithms?  (The first lesson is that you _will not_ get the clocks of multiple computers synchronized.)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I really understand what you're asking for, but IMO something like an actor model will likely get you on the path. There are a number of implementations. You might want to look into something functional as well (like Clojure).

Comment: @LouisWasserman I just asked on ServerFault: http://serverfault.com/questions/394967/what-is-a-realistic-average-time-difference-between-servers-in-the-same-lan  The expected difference is 10-20ms, so well below 1 second. The batches do not have to be processed at exactly the same time, they just have to be processed with the same content and in the same order.

Comment: @DaveNewton I was actually planning on using an actor system, but I don't see how an actor system would help me make sure that 3 actors located on different machines always process their event in the same order, if they receive them in different order? If you can tell me that, then my vote goes to you.

Comment: @SebastienDiot The actor part doesn't help that specifically. If they're sortable as you claim, it doesn't matter what order they're received in, they can always be *processed* in a specific order.

Comment: @DaveNewton I think either you know something that you think is obvious, but that I don't know, or you underestimate the problem. The problem is that each process has at some point to decide which event to process, *based on the ones it received*, and each process can have received *different events*. *Eventually* they will get all the events, but they cannot wait for ever to process them, and they cannot know which events they are missing until they actually have them all. And since the event flow is continuous, there is no clear point when they know they reached the end.

Comment: @SebastienDiot But you said the servers had to reach a consensus; how could servers ever reach consensus if at least two of them hadn't received the same events? Meh--you're right, I don't understand what you're asking for, as I stated in the first comment--never mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the question and your follow-up there probably "wasn't" an API to satisfy your requirements.  To day you could take a look at the Kafka (from LinkedIn)

- [Apache Kafka](http://kafka.apache.org/)

And the general concept of "a log" entity, in what folks like to call 'big data':

- [The Log: What every software engineer should know about real-time data's unifying abstraction](http://engineering.linkedin.com/distributed-systems/log-what-every-software-engineer-should-know-about-real-time-datas-unifying)

Actually for your question, I'd begin with the blog about "the log".  In my terms the way it works -- And Kafka isn't the only package out doing log handling -- Works as follows:

- Instead of a queue based message-passing / publish-subscribe
- Kafka uses a "log" of messages
- Subscribers (or end-points) can consume the log
- The log guarantees to be "in-order"; it handles giga-data, is fast

  - Double check on the guarantee, there's usually a trade-off for reliability
- You just read the log, I think reads are destructive as the default.
- If there's a subscriber group, everyone can 'read' before the log-entry dies.

The basic handling (compute) process for the log, is a Map-Reduce-Filter model so you read-everything really fast; keep only stuff you want; process it (reduce) produce outcome(s).

The downside seems to be you need clusters and stuff to make it really shine.  Since different servers or sites was mentioned I think we are still on track.  I found it a finicky to get up-and-running with the Apache downloads because the tend to assume non-Windows environments (*ho hum*).

The other 'fast' option would be

- [Apache Apollo](http://www.infoq.com/news/2011/12/apollo-benchmarks)

Which would need you to do the plumbing for connecting different servers.  Since the requirements include ...

> servers that receive events. They start with the same initial state, and should keep in sync by agreeing on which event to process in which order. Luckily for me, the events are not to be processed ASAP, but "in a bit", so that I have some time to get the servers to agree before the deadline

I suggest looking at a ["Getting Started" example or tutorial with Kafka](https://www.google.com.au/search?num=50&newwindow=1&q=simple%20kafka%20demo&oq=simple%20kafka%20demo) and then looking at similar ZooKeeper organised message/log software(s).  Good luck  and Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

So far I haven't got a clear answer, but I think it would be useful anyone interested to see what I found.

Here are some theoretical discussions related to the subject:

[Dynamic Vector Clocks for Consistent Ordering of Events](http://www.vs.inf.ethz.ch/edu/HS2010/VS/exercises/DVC_Landes.pdf)

[Conflict-free Replicated Data Types](http://hal.inria.fr/docs/00/60/93/99/PDF/RR-7687.pdf)

One way of making multiple concurent process wait for each other, which I could use to synchronize the "batches" is a distributed barrier. One Java implementation seems to be available on top of [Hazelcast](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/31) and another uses [ZooKeeper](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/recipes.html#sc_recipes_eventHandles)

One simpler alternative I found is to use a DB. Every process inserts all events it receives into the DB. Depending on the DB design, this can be fully concurrent and lock-free, like in VoltDB, for example. Then at regular interval of one second, some "cron job" runs that selects and marks the events to be processed in the next batch. The job can run on every server. The first to run the job for one batches fixes the set of events, so that the others just get to use the list that the first one defined. Like that we have a guarantee that all batches contain the same set of event on all servers. And if we can use a complete order over the whole batch, which the cron job could specify itself, then the state of the servers will be kept in sync.